# How Should Form Input be Encrypted for sending to a Server?

Tags: encryption, implementation, file-encryption

I apologise if this question is a duplicate.  I couldn't find any similar questions.

I am writing a web app that consists of a series of drop-down style question menus.  These generate more drop-downs as questions are answered.

I want to use the end user's answers to the presented questions to generate a JSON file (or similar) and have the client send this back to my server.

I was planning on using a standard SSL certificate to do this.  However it has occurred to me that given the data has an underlying structure this might make it susceptible to brute force attacks.

IE a user registers an account on my server.  Tries the options and encrypts them with my public key.  As the data will be identical to the data generated by any other user that selects the same options they would then be able to determine the input data fairly easily because they would just compare their own transmitted cipher-texts with the cipher-text my other users were sending.

The data is anonymous but would be of an extremely sensitive nature if it could be traced as belonging to a specific individual.  (The software is for helping semi-legal advisers interview their clients).

This can't be a new problem.  So is there a standard accepted way to solve this issue?

Comment: Use a modern TLS version, don't try to re-invent the wheel. Saying "... make it susceptible to brute force attacks" is missing quite a few things about how TLS works.

Comment: @Marc Sorry I don't follow what you are saying.  Does TLS assign a private key to the client as well as the server?

Comment: A symmetric key is generated for each connection, with public cryptography being used to securely exchange said session key. This means that to brute-force a particular message, you would need to figure out the session key first which boils down to breaking public key cryptography. With modern enough ciphers (enforced by the TLS version and client/server support), this is computationally infeasible (inserver standard disclaimer). I recommend you start from the [wikipedia page on TLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security) and keep reading from there.

Comment: So to answer your question, the "accepted way" of solving this is to use TLS.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll take a look.